# Add a new line of text to an existing file in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to the Scala. I want to add a new line of text to an existing file.

I have tried the code below, but it is overwriting the existing text:

```
println("plese enter the text")
val text = Console.readLine()
val write = new PrintWriter(new File("Test.txt"))
write.write(text) 
write.close()
```

please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a java api question

You can do

```
val write = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.txt"),true)))
```

This will open the file in append mode and not overwrite mode.

Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649989/how-to-parse-json-with-lift-json-in-scala

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! One suggestion: maybe you meant to say "writer" instead of "write". Edit: oops, the example code originally had the error. Ignore this, please!