# How to parse JSON with lift-json in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalability, scala-collections, scalaz

When I am trying parse the json object I am getting the below error.

```
import net.liftweb.json._

object SarahEmailPluginConfigTest {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

  val json = parse("""{"url": "imap.yahoo.com", "username": "myusername", "password": "mypassword" }""")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
    println(m.url)
    println(m.username)
    println(m.password)
  }
}
```

I have added "lift-json_2.9.0-1-2.4.jar " to my build path and I am getting following error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats
>
> not enough arguments for method extract: (implicit formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[MailServer])MailServer. Unspecified value parameters formats, mf

Comment: not sure about this particular library, but it sounds like you need to register your case class. `implicit val formats = DefaultFormats` is probably enough for a base set of types, but you are adding your own and might need to provide an implicit format for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me on scala `2.11.7` and `lift-json-2.6.2`.  What version of scala are you using?  From the name of the `jar` you gave above you should be using scala `2.9.*` which is pretty old.  If you're not on scala `2.9.*` I guess it is because of binary incompatibilities between the Scala versions.  If you are using `sbt`, try the following as `build.sbt`:

```
name := "<name of your project>"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6.2"
```

You can then remove the old `jar` file because `sbt` takes care of that for you.